# Percent unit from CSS to Kotlin React?

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I was trying to use the percent unit (%) from CSS to my Kotlin React file, it has the others unit but I cant find this one. I was looking in Length.kt. If there's not that unit, how could I do the same? I'm trying to make an input with 50% height compared to its parent. I'm new in Kotlin. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Try 50.pct - That's how it works in Kotlin React

Comment: Is there a documentation for hwo CSS is translated into Kotlin?

Comment: I haven't found documentation - just information I've learned from tutorials, and trial and error :/